# When Chrome downloads PDF files and I move them out of the download folder to the desktop they are locked from any changes

Tags: google-chrome, download

When I use Chrome to download a PDF file, it goes by default to the Downloads folder.  When I drag this file to the desktop (Windows 7), the file is then disassociated from any user, and I am not allowed to rename or delete or move the file.  Even responding to the "administrator access required" prompts doesn't allow the operation.  I have to go into the file security settings and add a user and permissions to the file in order to unlock it.

This doesn't happen when I download a file with IE.

How do I prevent this?  I have searched for Chrome download settings but don't find anything relevant.

Comment: -click Chrome control button (top left)
-Settings->scroll->show advanced settings
-scroll->Downloads->change

Choose desktop as default downloads location

Do your download again

Comment: OK, but I don't want to change the download location, I just want to be able to work with the downloaded files without restriction.  I.e. move them to another location and then rename them or delete them.